# Adding import after line is written?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio automatically adds imports when choosing the right one from a list. However I often find myself typing the whole line myself and get the `Cannot resolve symbol...` error. In Eclipse I would hover over the yet to be imported class and get the option to add this, is this somehow possible with Android Studio? One would think it would be listed add the error (red light bulb) but it just asks me if I want to create the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press Alt+Enter while your cursor is in the unresolved symbol to bring up a list of options to attempt to resolve the symbol. If Android Studio finds one or more classes with a matching name, it will list them and give you the option to import them.